# Marking single table values with dot alignment

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment, siunitx, pgfplotstable

I have a table with multiple columns that I have aligned with the S column type from siuntx. In each column I want to mark some special values in a clear and subtle way, I've used the * symbol for that. The problem is that two of the columns contain numbers with only one decimal value and the rest with two decimal values. When compiling the * symbol is not aligned next to the number as this picture shows:

[image: my table]

I've tried using bold type for marking but that smashed the horizontal alignment completely. I also cannot just add some 0s to the shorter columns for scientific reasons. What can I do to fix this? Here's my MWE:

```
    \documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}


\begin{document}

\begin{table}
        \centering
        \caption{some table}
        \begin{tabular}{lSSSSSS}\toprule
            Probe & {Ti} & {Al} & {N} & {O} & {H} & {C} \\\midrule
            AAV-1   &21.4   &28.1   &49.2   &0.60*  &0.62*  &0.00    \\
            AAV-2   &21.4   &28.5   &49.0   &0.66*  &0.47   &0.00    \\
            AAV-3   &21.4   &28.9   &49.3   &0.34   &0.04*  &0.00    \\
            AAV-4   &21.5*  &29.1   &49.0*  &0.30*  &0.12   &0.00    \\
            AAV-4-1 &22.1*  &27.4*  &48.3*  &1.32   &0.84*  &0.00    \\
            AAV-5   &20.2*  &29.3   &49.2   &0.73   &0.58   &0.00    \\
            AAV-6   &20.6*  &29.3*  &48.6   &0.74   &0.33   &0.34    \\
            AAV-7   &20.6   &28.9*  &49.8   &0.53*  &0.24   &0.00    \\
            \bottomrule
        \end {tabular}\par
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can specify the format of the numbers in the columns:

[image]

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}


\begin{document}

\begin{table}
        \centering
        \caption{some table}
        \begin{tabular}{l *{3}{S[table-format=2.1]} *{3}{S[table-format=1.2]}}\toprule
            Probe & {Ti} & {Al} & {N} & {O} & {H} & {C} \\\midrule
            AAV-1   &21.4   &28.1   &49.2   &0.60*  &0.62*  &0.00    \\
            AAV-2   &21.4   &28.5   &49.0   &0.66*  &0.47   &0.00    \\
            AAV-3   &21.4   &28.9   &49.3   &0.34   &0.04*  &0.00    \\
            AAV-4   &21.5*  &29.1   &49.0*  &0.30*  &0.12   &0.00    \\
            AAV-4-1 &22.1*  &27.4*  &48.3*  &1.32   &0.84*  &0.00    \\
            AAV-5   &20.2*  &29.3   &49.2   &0.73   &0.58   &0.00    \\
            AAV-6   &20.6*  &29.3*  &48.6   &0.74   &0.33   &0.34    \\
            AAV-7   &20.6   &28.9*  &49.8   &0.53*  &0.24   &0.00    \\
            \bottomrule
        \end {tabular}\par
\end{table}

\end{document}
```